# How to get different distinct sales from same table

Tags: mysql

Im having trouble to get the distinct sales from my DB, I tried INNER JOIN but it doesn't work. My SQL statement is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(mta.Maintenance.userId)  AS a
FROM mta.Maintenance WHERE 1=1)  AS t 
INNER JOIN mta.Maintenance
ON t.a = mta.Maintenance.userId 
WHERE 1=1
AND mta.Maintenance.paymentStatus = 'PAID' 
AND mta.Maintenance.createdAt < 1648771199000 
AND mta.Maintenance.createdAt > 1640995199000 
AND mta.Maintenance.deletedAt IS NULL 
AND mta.Maintenance.price > 50
```

And the table is something like this:

| a | maintenanceId | adminId | storeId | vehicleId | serviceId | paymentStatus | status | createdAt | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | 50 | \N | 6 | 26 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644237405347 | 65 |
| 71 | 70 | 28 | 3 | 32 | 32 | PAID | PENDING | 1644499807732 | 71 |
| 71 | 72 | 52 | 3 | 34 | 30 | PAID | PENDING | 1644851796531 | 71 |
| 78 | 75 | 52 | 6 | 36 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644858138158 | 78 |
| 78 | 76 | 52 | 6 | 37 | 91 | PAID | PENDING | 1644863060421 | 78 |

And I want:

| a | maintenanceId | adminId | storeId | vehicleId | serviceId | paymentStatus | status | createdAt | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | 50 | \N | 6 | 26 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644237405347 | 65 |
| 71 | 70 | 28 | 3 | 32 | 32 | PAID | PENDING | 1644499807732 | 71 |
| 78 | 75 | 52 | 6 | 36 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644858138158 | 78 |

Basically the distincts results with the MIN(createdAt).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) to group the rows by `UserId` and assign a sort number based on the `CreatedAt` value. Then grab rows `where SortNum = 1`

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CreatedAt ASC) AS SortNum
   FROM   Maintenance
)
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  RowNum = 1
```

| a | maintenanceId | adminId | storeId | vehicleId | serviceId | paymentStatus | status | createdAt | userId | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | 50 | N | 6 | 26 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644237405347 | 65 | 1 |
| 71 | 70 | 28 | 3 | 32 | 32 | PAID | PENDING | 1644499807732 | 71 | 1 |
| 78 | 75 | 52 | 6 | 36 | 38 | PAID | PENDING | 1644858138158 | 78 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9aafd5ea71ca7636a75919c03365625a)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **[MySQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_in.asp)** of MySQL and from there select the `min(createdat)` column and group them by `a` in the main query.

```
SELECT * FROM maintenance a
WHERE createdat 
IN (SELECT MIN(createdat) FROM maintenance b WHERE b.a=a.a) 
GROUP BY a;
```

**RESULT**

```
     a  maintenanceId  adminId  storeId  vehicleId  serviceId  paymentStatus  STATUS       createdAt  userId  
------  -------------  -------  -------  ---------  ---------  -------------  -------  -------------  --------
    65             50   (NULL)        6         26         38  PAID           PENDING  1644237405347        65
    71             70       28        3         32         32  PAID           PENDING  1644499807732        71
    78             75       52        6         36         38  PAID           PENDING  1644858138158        78
```